# Pass criteria from text box with Like

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a form that has a list box for multiple selection of criteria for a query.  The text box is populated with the list of values from the list box in the format of Like "*2299*" Or Like "*2265*" Or Like "*5522*".  How can this be passed to query criteria?  I have tried InStr(***) and In (***) but not successful as of yet.  If I copy from the text box and paste in the criteria field of the query, it works perfectly.  But how do I pass it to the query to use as criteria/ parameter?

Comment: Did you try `like "*2299*" or like "*2265*" or like "*5522*"` . You can drop the first `*` if you want your string to start with those 4 numbers.

Comment: Using this to find Sites that contain those values ex: 852265P, 522299RPrivate Sub lbSite_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim strMultiValue
For i = 0 To lbSite.ListCount - 1
    If lbSite.Selected(i) Then
        strMultiValue = strMultiValue & "Like ""*" & lbSite.Column(1, i) & "*"" Or "
    End If
Next i
If Len(strMultiValue) > 2 Then
    strMultiValue = Left(strMultiValue, Len(strMultiValue) - 3)
    Me.txtSA.Value = strMultiValue
Else
    Me.txtSA.Value = Null
End If
Me!txtSA.Requery

End Sub

Comment: Yes, that is the format it goes in to the list box as ex: Like "*2299*" or Like "*2265*" or Like "*5522*". the InStr([Forms]![frmBUA]![txtSA]) nor In ([Forms]![frmBUA]![txtSA]) seem to be what is needed for it to pass into the query

Comment: I'll check your code later, but in order for the `like` to work, you need to put * before and/or after your search string. Can you change your 6th line with this: `strMultiValue = strMultiValue & "Like *""" & lbSite.Column(1, i) & "*"" Or "` and try?

Comment: code it has the *, but after submitting it here doesn't show them.But they are there in the code.The format is correct in the text box, I just need it to pass to the query to do the search.suggested code moves the * in front of the " so the format doesn't work when pasting it in the query criteria field manually.I am looking to take the results of the text field with the created criteria and pass it to the criteria line in an append query.If I manually copy and paste it brings in the correct results but I can't get it to do it automatically when selecting the button with VBA to run the query